# Is it worth upgrading to the F-POD from the C-POD?

Tags: equipment, cpod

My lab recently went to purchase some replacement C-PODs (made by [Chelonia Limited](https://chelonia.co.uk/index.html)), and were given the pitch up about upgrading to the F-POD.

Does anyone have any experience with these? Are they different? What are the practical points of upgrading? Is the data comparable to the C-POD?

Answer (score 8):

My lab has been working with F-PODs for about 6 months now, and there are some noticeable differences. However, I will say that over all it is the same system.

The major benefit of the F-POD over the C-POD is that you can use any microSD card with the unit, not one that has been specifically formatted for that C-POD to ensure that the gain settings are correct. That data is stored internally on the F-POD now. Additionally, you can now mark the exact time you turn the unit off as well as marking the time when you turn it on, and it doesn't need to be exactly on the minute. You still need to input a datetime into fpod.exe so the F-POD has a reference, but it can be from the start or the end of the deployment. So if someone forgets to do it at the start, it's only a big deal if you collect it after the batteries die.

In theory the KERNO classifier in the F-POD should be the same as the C-POD. However, my colleague is testing this, and plans on writing up those results this summer. Stay tuned...

Comment: As the designer of the F-POD and the KERNO-F classifier I can say that the big difference is in dolphin detections - short broadband clicks. The detection rate goes up by a large factor, typically more than 3, even though the false positive rate has gone down. For porpoises and other narrow band high frequency species the increase in detections is much smaller.  The F-POD does have clock and knows its start and end times.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Good to see you on here. :)